# Polymorphic relationship with mixin

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When using the `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationships in Ember-Data, does it have to specify a class, or can I specify a mixin? For instance, I have an `Attachement` model that I want to link to some other models. Specifically, I want to assign `Attachement`s to `Project`s and `Components`. Can I use a mixin on `Projects` and `Component` and use that mixin as the inverse like below?

```
App.Attachment = DS.Model.extend({
    attachedTo: DS.belongsTo('canHaveAttachments', { inverse: 'attachments'});
});

App.CanHaveAttachmentsMixin = DS.Mixin.create({});

App.Project = DS.Model.extend(App.CanHaveAttachmentsMixin, {
    attachments: DS.hasMany('attachment', { inverse: 'attachedTo' });
});
```

Is that something officially supported by Ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spent the last day testing and researching this problem and I've finally found the answer: no. I did quite a bit of testing and couldn't get it to work. Finally, I figured out that it's because mixins (as far as I can tell) aren't in the prototype chain of an object.

To solve the problem, I just ended up using multiple relationships instead of a single polymorphic one. It's not quite as object oriented, but it's more explicit.

Answer (score 6):

In our project using Ember 2.4, we have few entities, Task, Assignment and Tag. Task are **taggable** and **assignable** through polymorphic associations.

This is our models structure:

```
// app/models/task.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Taggable from 'app/mixins/taggable';
import Assignable from 'app/mixins/assignable';

export default DS.Model.extend(Taggable, Assignable, {  

});

// app/models/tag.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  taggable: DS.belongsTo('taggable', { polymorphic: true }),
});

// app/models/assignment.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  assignable: DS.belongsTo('assignable', { polymorphic: true }),
});


// app/mixins/taggable.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  tag: DS.belongsTo('tag'), // you can go with hasMany here, we only have one-to-one association
});


// app/mixins/assignable.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  assignment: DS.belongsTo('assignment'), // you can go with hasMany here, we only have one-to-one association
});
```